# How to read from a file every 5 seconds in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, timer

I am trying to make my program read from a file every 5 seconds until it reaches its end.

I have this code:

```
data = pd.read_csv(path + file_name)
n = len(data.index)
for i in range(0, n):
    element = data['first_column_name'][0]
```

I tried writing time.sleep(5) after reading the element, but it has to be from the beginning, to look like streaming data... if possible

How can I make it read the element from the file every 5 seconds?

Comment: I would like to do other stuff too within those seconds, yes!

Comment: @PaulRooney          yes!

Comment: So you are trying to simulate streaming data?

Comment: yes!! @PaulRooney

Comment: One option is to pass a chunksize argument pd.read_csv and just write to the file its reading at 5 second intervals. ?

Comment: I was searching on google how to make this, but it showed me that I can only choose a number of how much to read, not in seconds interval.. or can we just write chucksize = 5 s ? can you please tell me how do i make it ? @PaulRooney

Answer (score 0):

Python is by default single threaded, meaning that it only executes one thing at a time. When you use time.sleep, python can do nothing else but watch this timer count down. You seem to want your program to do stuff and periodically check on a file. What I think you are looking for is async/multithreading. This is a big topic with lots of different options for different circumstances; [this](https://realpython.com/python-async-features/) Real Python article gives a gentle introduction.